# How do I prevent a <td> from being too high?

Tags: html, formatting

It must be something stupid, but I can't figure it out so far...

Here is my HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td style="height: 8px"><img src="/media/note2.png" width="8" height="8" border="0"></td>
    <td style="height: 8px"></td>
    <td style="height: 8px"><img src="/media/note1.png" width="8" height="8" border="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="NoteCell"></td>
    <td class="NoteCell">{{ text }}</td>
    <td class="NoteCell"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="height: 8px"><img src="/media/note4.png" width="8" height="8" border="0"></td>
    <td style="height: 8px"></td>
    <td style="height: 8px"><img src="/media/note3.png" width="8" height="8" border="0"></td>
</tr>
```

I'm expecting the first and third rows to have a height of 8 pixels, but for some reason they are much higher (as if there was text inside, but there is no text!)

Puzzled... Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Without your CSS I can't be 100% sure, but what does setting `line-height: 8px` on those `<td>` elements do?

Comment: Which browsers show this behaviour?

Comment: I removed all the css and it still happens.

Both IE and Chrome show this behaviour.

Setting "line-height: 8px" did decrease the height to some extent, but the third row is still higher than 8px.

Another piece of info: The problem is not reproduced if I remove the line <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Traditional//EN"> from the top of the document.

Comment: Did you try removing the images? They might be the cause, check they don't have any padding on.

Comment: Removing the images decreased the height, but I need the images so it's not a feasible solution. Alohci's answer worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, Nick, Frank and SLC for trying to help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `td img { display: block; }`

Comment: @adius - As the OP said "as if there was text inside". That's exactly it. The image, being by default a replaced inline element, is placed in a line box. All line boxes contain a [strut](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut), a zero-width anonymous box formed from the  the font-size and line-height of a text character in the container element and vertically aligned to the baseline. It is the strut that creates the extra height. Making the image `display:block' means that it's not in a line box. The line box is never created, and there is no strut, so no extra height.

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote.  I misread the answer.  It's locked in now and I can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the second columns of 1st and 3rd row define the minimum height.

Note that all the columns in a row will have same height and all rows in a column will have same width.

That's how the tables are rendered.

So, you will have to additionally write:

```
td { font-size: 8px; }
```

EDIT: Fixed `fontsize` to `font-size`

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately this didn't help. There is no text inside anyway.

Comment: I think he intended to write:  td { font-size: 8px; }

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1. Paste your code snippet into an empty html page and find out if the problem still occurs, make sure the doc type is the same as the target page.

Tip 2. Use a browser extension with CSS debug facilities, check and fiddle with the css that gets applied to your table rows, cells and images in the cells.

Tip 3. You could try if one of these help by adding them all:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed}
td,tr {padding:0}
td img {margin:0;height:8px}
```

If it helps, it means that other definitions in your stylesheet make the cells or rows higher. By removing my css suggestions one by one, you can find out what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and `vertical-align:top;` did the trick for me.